# The better way to maintain css, js, font-cion, image's versions?

Tags: javascript, css, project-management

I have few css files for a site and some css properties are shared through all of them. Plus there are also few js files. font icons file and images that I constantly updating. Whenever I tried to push to main repository, i had to make sure each file version are bumped using "?=number". I am seriously tired of doing this. 
Is there a better way to do URL version bumps all together? Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info: I am using IIS7/8 and developing in windows system by using HG Mercurial. Back end  uses asp.net visual basic, mysql.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided us with some additional information such as what version control software you are using and your operating system.

Comment: If you're talking about rewriting URLs to force *browsers* to bump them, then we need to know what server-side language, framework, etc you are using as well.

Comment: I am using IIS7/8 and developing in windows system by using HG Mercurial. Biscally back end team uses asp.net visual basic, mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET, your .NET devs can set a variable that holds a common increment number that you can use as the number in the ?v=number part. So, you just change all of your CSS/JS files to consume the variable one time only. For example:

```
string version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VersionNumber"];
```

If you're using bundling, there is a better answer here:

[How to make bundles unminify and list individual files when using a cookieless static content server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390241/how-to-make-bundles-unminify-and-list-individual-files-when-using-a-cookieless-s)